# Are these rowan berries? Yes or no, are they edible?

Tags: tree-identification

Am I correct in assuming that these are rowan berries? I have little experience, but have learned that the appearance of the bark matches. The tree is located in northern Germany (northern German lowlands). It stands somewhat apart from other trees.
Wikipedia says these berries are "limitedly edible". If I had to eat them to survive, could I eat them? Can you tell me a little more about these berries and trees?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Rowan (Sorbus) berries look like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rowan). At least in Finland :-) The berries are edible but taste a bit bitter. I won't bother collecting them for consumption, but they have their uses.

Comment: I voted to keep open.  It is a brief question with parts that are logically connected, and a complete answer would address the parts.  Splitting this question into parts would scatter information about the berries and make it difficult for a user to assemble the information he would want and need.  That is, "Yes, they are rowan berries but you have to go to another question to find out if you can eat them.  And why should we tell you anything else?"

Answer (score 8):

The rowan tree's leaves grow in opposite pairs off the stem, not alternately as shown here, and its fruits are red.

I suggest that the tree is **bird cherry** or [*prunus avium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_avium)  and its fruits are bitter.

Its habitat includes much of central Europe.

[image]

Comment: Yup, this looks like wild cherry to me too. I disagree with taste though. Dark red (purple/black) fruit is quite tasty to me, cherry-like though I prefer it over ordinary cultivated cherries. The main problem is that there isn't much to eat, nearly everything is just stone. But note that bright red fruit (eg those red ones in question's first image) isn't ripe yet and indeed tastes sour/bitter.

Comment: @ZizyArcher the [wild cherry and bird cherry](https://www.keele.ac.uk/arboretum/nationalcollectionoffloweringcherries/aboutcherries/) aren't quite the same tree. The wild cherry fruit is redder than those shown here.